# C# Custom Attribute for System.Windows.Forms.Button class

Tags: c#, winforms, nested, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to extend the **System.Windows.Forms.Button** class with a couple of properties.
What I'd like to achieve is to have two different colours, for **BackColor** and **ForeColor**, based on the **Enabled** property.

Everything looks good in the Designer, 
however, when I try to change the colours nothing happens.
If I close the form window and reopen it the values are missing or reset to the default.

I don't know what I'm missing but there's obviously something I'm doing wrong or not doing at all. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help

This is the class I'm currently using to inherit the Button:

```
public partial class ZButton : Button
{
    public ZButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetAppearance();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    [Description("The background color of the component"), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public new EnableDisableAppearance BackColor { get { return backcolor; } set { backcolor = value; SetAppearance(); } }
    private EnableDisableAppearance backcolor = new EnableDisableAppearance();

    [Description("The text color of the component"), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public new EnableDisableAppearance ForeColor { get { return forecolor; } set { forecolor = value; SetAppearance(); } }
    private EnableDisableAppearance forecolor = new EnableDisableAppearance();

    public new bool Enabled { get { return enabled; } set { enabled = value; SetAppearance(); } }
    private bool enabled = true;

    private void SetAppearance()
    {
        base.BackColor = (enabled ? backcolor.Enabled : backcolor.Disabled);
        base.ForeColor = (enabled ? forecolor.Enabled : forecolor.Disabled);
    }
}
```

Here's the Attribute and TypeConverter class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnableDisableAppearanceTypeConverter))]
public class EnableDisableAppearance : Attribute
{

    public EnableDisableAppearance()
    {
    }
    public EnableDisableAppearance(Color enabled, Color disabled)
    {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    [Description("Color when enabled"), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LightGray")]
    public Color Enabled { get { return enabled; } set { enabled = value; } }
    private Color enabled = new Color();

    [Description("Color when disabled"), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "DarkGray")]
    public Color Disabled { get { return disabled; } set { disabled = value; } }
    private Color disabled = new Color();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret = "";

        if (enabled.IsKnownColor) { ret += "Enabled " + enabled.ToString(); }
        else { ret += string.Format("Enabled [{0}, {1}, {2}]", enabled.R.ToString(), enabled.G.ToString(), enabled.B.ToString()); }

        if (disabled.IsKnownColor) { ret += ", Disabled " + disabled.ToString(); }
        else { ret += string.Format(", Disabled [{0}, {1}, {2}]", disabled.R.ToString(), disabled.G.ToString(), disabled.B.ToString()); }

        return ret.Replace("Color ", "");
    }

}

public class EnableDisableAppearanceTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true; //base.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(EnableDisableAppearance));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the appearance in the setter when assigning a new `EnableDisableAppearance` object; however, when changing the color within an existing object (i.e in the setter of `Enabled` and `Disabled`) you are not setting the colors. Also, you are hiding existing properties. If you access them through an object statically typed as `ZButton` you will see them; however, not through `Button` ot `Control`.

Comment: Do you mean something like     private EnableDisableAppearance backcolor = new EnableDisableAppearance();  ? About the fact I need to have an object typed as ZButton to see the properties, I'm ok with it. Saying "extend the Button class" was a bad choice of words, I'd like to keep the standard Button as it is, I'm just inheriting it and adding/overriding properties.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `private EnableDisableAppearance backcolor = new EnableDisableAppearance(System.Drawing.Color.White, System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);`

Comment: I mean, here you are calling `SetAppearance`: `public new EnableDisableAppearance BackColor { get { return backcolor; } set { backcolor = value; SetAppearance(); } }` but not here: `public Color Enabled { get { return enabled; } set { enabled = value; } }`

Comment: I've managed to have it working by changing the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` from `Content` `Visible`, however, in Design it's still showing the default colour instead of the one I choose. To see the colour I've just chosen in the Designer I have to close and reopen the form window. About using the `SetAppearance()`, those are two different classes and the `EnableDisableAppearance` classes has no knowledge of what the base class is. I thought I could keep them separate and use the `EnableDisableAppearance` where I needed. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that; however, you should add some notification mechanism in the setters of `Enabled` and `Disabled` (e.g. an event), so that `SetAppearance()` gets called in the other class. The other class then would have to attach to this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the `ZButton` when the `Enabled` or `Disabled` properties have changed in `EnableDisableAppearance`. For this, add an event and raise it when the properties change. Only showing the additional code:

```
public class EnableDisableAppearance : Attribute
{
    public event EventHandler AppearanceChanged;

    protected virtual void OnAppearanceChanged()
    {
        AppearanceChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    [Description("Color when enabled"), ...]
    public Color Enabled
    {
        get { return enabled; }
        set {
            if (value != enabled) {
                enabled = value;
                OnAppearanceChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    // Do the same in the Disabled property...

    ...
}
```

The `ZButton` must carefully attach and detach the event

```
public partial class ZButton : Button
{
    private void Backcolor_AppearanceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAppearance();
    }

    [Description("The background color ...]
    public new EnableDisableAppearance BackColor
    {
        get { return backcolor; }
        set {
            if (value != backcolor) {
                if (backcolor != null) {
                    // Detach event handler from old appearance object
                    backcolor.AppearanceChanged -= Backcolor_AppearanceChanged;
                }
                backcolor = value;
                SetAppearance();
                if (backcolor != null) {
                    // Attach event handler to new appearance object
                    backcolor.AppearanceChanged += Backcolor_AppearanceChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Same for ForeColor...

    ...
}
```

Add some null checking for safety

```
private void SetAppearance()
{
    if (backcolor != null)
        base.BackColor = enabled ? backcolor.Enabled : backcolor.Disabled;
    if (forecolor != null)
        base.ForeColor = enabled ? forecolor.Enabled : forecolor.Disabled;
}
```

Comment: I previously tried with INotifyPropertyChanged, unfortunately it wasn't working for me. Your approach works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should work with `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. Excatly the same procedure, except that you must pass the property name to the event. But i see no advantage, except if you are using object binding to display a `EnableDisableAppearance` object itself in a form.

Comment: I'll give it a go in case I need to add more properties, at the moment your solution looks good. Thanks again.